# PHPUnit with abstract class using trait

Tags: php, class, inheritance, phpunit, traits

I have an abstract class *DatabaseManager* with quite some children like *General_db_manager*, *Data_Importer*, *Translation_Manager*, etc. which used to work properly. It is still working properly when I'm not running my unit test actually...

I just finished writing this *ExceptionLogger* class which required database connection, but I didn't want it to be a children of *DataBaseManager* since I'm planning to use it in *DatabaseManager* (and I want to avoid "diamond of death").

So I putted out some of *DatabaseManager* code in a traits like this:

```
trait ConnectionnHelper{


    protected static $support_user = "not_real_value";

    protected static $support_pass = "Not_real_value";

    protected static $whitelist = array('127.0.0.1.', "::1");


    /**
    * Return the host for a connection to our mysql server database.
    *
    * @return String
    */ 
    protected static function getMySqlHost() {

        $host = "";

        if (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {

            if (in_array(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'), self::$whitelist)) {

                $host = "127.0.0.1.";
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

            if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], self::$whitelist)) {

                $host = "127.0.0.1.";
            }
        }
        elseif(!getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') and !isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

            $host = "127.0.0.1.";
        }

        return $host;   
    }
}
```

And I included my trait both in my *DataBaseManager* and my *ExceptionLogger*.

```
abstract class DataBaseManager {

    use ConnectionHelper;
```

When I remove the "*use ConnectionnHelper*", my unit test runs without error; but if I keep it, I receive result like this :

```
FILE : BACKUP_MANAGER_TEST.PHP

Fatal error: Class 'DataBaseManager' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\general_controler\general_db_manager.php on line 14


FILE : GC_DATA_IMPORTER_TEST.PHP

Fatal error: Class 'DataBaseManager' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\general_controler\general_db_manager.php on line 14
```

What bugs me is that my trait is doesn't require any class. So, I'm not so sure why it require my *GeneralDBManager* class which is also a children of *DatabaseManager* and is running without error

```
FILE : GENERAL_DB_MANAGER_TEST.PHP

PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.....

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (5 tests, 22 assertions)
```

Here's my line 14 in GeneralDBManager (and the only require in the class):

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '../database_manager.php');

class generalDbManager extends DataBaseManager{
```

No error neither in my *ExceptionLogger*:

```
FILE : EXCEPTION_LOGGER_TEST.PHP

PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

Is anyone already faced a similar problem?

Thank you,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's solution to my problem for those who are interested.

First I tried to add an abstract class *connection_manager* which would be the parent of both to *exception_logger* and *database_manager* (this is probably a better design than using trait anyway...)

Yet, I still had the same problem:

```
FILE : BACKUP_MANAGER_TEST.PHP

Fatal error: Class 'DataBaseManager' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\general_controler\general_db_manager.php on line 14
```

As it seems, there's some kind of circular requirement that PHP seems to be able to deal with, but not PHPunit.

To visualize my solution, let's suppose you got a test class like this one:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../backup_manager.php');

class BackupManagerTest extends phpunit_framework_testcase {

    public function setUp(){}

    public function tearDown(){}

    public function testGetBackupMode(){

        //test 1
        $myTag = BackupManager::getBackupMode("test");

        $this->assertNotEmpty($myTag);

        $this->assertContains('type="radio"', $myTag);

        $this->assertContains('value="1"', $myTag);

        $this->assertContains('value="2"', $myTag);

        $this->assertContains('id="1_RADIO" name="test" checked', $myTag);

        //test 2
        $myTag = BackupManager::getBackupMode("woot", BackupMode::BACKUP_SELECTED);

        $this->assertNotEmpty($myTag);

        $this->assertContains('id="2_RADIO" name="woot" checked', $myTag);


        //test 3
        $myTag = BackupManager::getBackupMode("blu", -10);

        $this->assertNotEmpty($myTag);

        $this->assertContains('id="1_RADIO" name="blu" checked', $myTag);
    }
}
```

I was able to solve the problem by adding an require for the *general_db_manager* that causes the problem right before the require for the classes having problems in their test files. By example:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../../../general_controler/general_db_manager.php');
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../backup_manager.php');
```

Et voilà, my magic charm is working!

```
FILE : BACKUP_MANAGER_TEST.PHP

PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.00Mb

OK (1 test, 9 assertions)
```

Of course, this is not an excuse for not seeking for the very best class design, yet it should save some headache to some poor programmers in despair.

Have a nice day,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal